# Metaclass Mixin or Chaining?

Tags: python, metaclass

Is it possible to chain metaclasses?

I have class `Model` which uses `__metaclass__=ModelBase` to process its namespace dict. I'm going to inherit from it and "bind" another metaclass so it won't shade the original one.

First approach is to subclass `class MyModelBase(ModelBase)`:

```
MyModel(Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyModelBase # inherits from `ModelBase`
```

But is it possible just to chain them like mixins, without explicit subclassing? Something like

```
class MyModel(Model):
    __metaclass__ = (MyMixin, super(Model).__metaclass__)
```

... or even better: create a MixIn that will use `__metaclass__` from the direct parent of the class that uses it:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyMetaMixin, # Automagically uses `Model.__metaclass__`
```

---

The reason: For more flexibility in extending existing apps, I want to create a global mechanism for hooking into the process of `Model`, `Form`, ... definitions in Django so it can be changed at runtime.

A common mechanism would be much better than implementing multiple metaclasses with callback mixins.

---

With your help I finally managed to come up to a solution: metaclass `MetaProxy`.

The idea is: create a metaclass that invokes a callback to modify the namespace of the class being created, then, with the help of `__new__`, mutate into a metaclass of one of the parents

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Magical metaclass
class MetaProxy(type):
    """ Decorate the class being created & preserve __metaclass__ of the parent

        It executes two callbacks: before & after creation of a class, 
        that allows you to decorate them.

        Between two callbacks, it tries to locate any `__metaclass__` 
        in the parents (sorted in MRO). 
        If found — with the help of `__new__` method it
        mutates to the found base metaclass. 
        If not found — it just instantiates the given class.
        """

    @classmethod
    def pre_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        """ Decorate a class before creation """
        return (name, bases, attrs)

    @classmethod
    def post_new(cls, newclass):
        """ Decorate a class after creation """
        return newclass

    @classmethod
    def _mrobases(cls, bases):
        """ Expand tuple of base-classes ``bases`` in MRO """
        mrobases = []
        for base in bases:
            if base is not None: # We don't like `None` :)
                mrobases.extend(base.mro())
        return mrobases

    @classmethod
    def _find_parent_metaclass(cls, mrobases):
        """ Find any __metaclass__ callable in ``mrobases`` """
        for base in mrobases:
            if hasattr(base, '__metaclass__'):
                metacls = base.__metaclass__
                if metacls and not issubclass(metacls, cls): # don't call self again
                    return metacls#(name, bases, attrs)
        # Not found: use `type`
        return lambda name,bases,attrs: type.__new__(type, name, bases, attrs)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        mrobases = cls._mrobases(bases)
        name, bases, attrs = cls.pre_new(name, bases, attrs) # Decorate, pre-creation
        newclass = cls._find_parent_metaclass(mrobases)(name, bases, attrs)
        return cls.post_new(newclass) # Decorate, post-creation



# Testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Original classes. We won't touch them
    class ModelMeta(type):
        def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
            attrs['parentmeta'] = name
            return super(ModelMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    class Model(object):
        __metaclass__ = ModelMeta
        # Try to subclass me but don't forget about `ModelMeta`

    # Decorator metaclass
    class MyMeta(MetaProxy):
        """ Decorate a class

            Being a subclass of `MetaProxyDecorator`,
                it will call base metaclasses after decorating
            """
        @classmethod
        def pre_new(cls, name, bases, attrs):
            """ Set `washere` to classname """
            attrs['washere'] = name
            return super(MyMeta, cls).pre_new(name, bases, attrs)

        @classmethod
        def post_new(cls, newclass):
            """ Append '!' to `.washere` """
            newclass.washere += '!'
            return super(MyMeta, cls).post_new(newclass)

    # Here goes the inheritance...
    class MyModel(Model):
        __metaclass__ = MyMeta
        a=1
    class MyNewModel(MyModel):
        __metaclass__ = MyMeta # Still have to declare it: __metaclass__ do not inherit
        a=2
    class MyNewNewModel(MyNewModel):
        # Will use the original ModelMeta
        a=3

    class A(object):
        __metaclass__ = MyMeta # No __metaclass__ in parents: just instantiate
        a=4
    class B(A): 
        pass # MyMeta is not called until specified explicitly



    # Make sure we did everything right
    assert MyModel.a == 1
    assert MyNewModel.a == 2
    assert MyNewNewModel.a == 3
    assert A.a == 4

    # Make sure callback() worked
    assert hasattr(MyModel, 'washere')
    assert hasattr(MyNewModel, 'washere')
    assert hasattr(MyNewNewModel, 'washere') # inherited
    assert hasattr(A, 'washere')

    assert MyModel.washere == 'MyModel!'
    assert MyNewModel.washere == 'MyNewModel!'
    assert MyNewNewModel.washere == 'MyNewModel!' # inherited, so unchanged
    assert A.washere == 'A!'
```

Comment: In Python 3.4, this does not appear to assert correctly; line 113 fails (`MyModel` does not have the `washere` attribute)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can chain them like that, and I don't know how that would work either.

But you can make new metaclasses during runtime and use them. But that's a horrid hack. :)

zope.interface does something similar, it has an advisor metaclass, that will just do some things to the class after construction. If there was a metclass already, one of the things it will do it set that previous metaclass as the metaclass once it's finished.

(However, avoid doing these kinds of things unless you have to, or think it's fun.)

Comment: Oooh, now Django will get scary metaclass hacks too. Django *is* the new ZOpe. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

A type can have only one metaclass, because a metaclass simply states what the class statement does - having more than one would make no sense. For the same reason "chaining" makes no sense:  the first metaclass creates the type, so what is the 2nd supposed to do?

You will have to merge the two metaclasses (just like with any other class). But that can be tricky, especially if you don't really know what they do.

```
class MyModelBase(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        attr['MyModelBase'] = 'was here'
        return type.__new__(cls,name, bases, attr)

class MyMixin(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        attr['MyMixin'] = 'was here'
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)

class ChainedMeta(MyModelBase, MyMixin):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        # call both parents
        MyModelBase.__init__(cls,name, bases, attr)
        MyMixin.__init__(cls,name, bases, attr)

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attr):
        # so, how is the new type supposed to look?
        # maybe create the first
        t1 = MyModelBase.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)
        # and pass it's data on to the next?
        name = t1.__name__
        bases = tuple(t1.mro())
        attr = t1.__dict__.copy()
        t2 = MyMixin.__new__(cls, name, bases, attr)
        return t2

class Model(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyModelBase # inherits from `ModelBase`

class MyModel(Model):
    __metaclass__ = ChainedMeta

print MyModel.MyModelBase
print MyModel.MyMixin
```

As you can see this is involves some guesswork already, since you don't really know what the other metaclasses do. If both metaclasses are really simple this *might* work, but I wouldn't have too much confidence in a solution like this.

Writing a metaclass for metaclasses that merges multiple bases is left as an exercise to the reader ;-P

Comment: Everything's great, except for an explicit dependency on `MyModelBase` :)

Comment: "For the same reason "chaining" makes no sense" -- Why is that?  Chaining metaclasses should be done via inheritance.  In fact, since your metaclass extends the built-in metaclass `type`, you are already chaining them.  When you call your metaclass' base via `super()`, you could easily achieve chained metaclasses by multiple inheritance.

Comment: "A type can have only one metaclass, because a metaclass simply states what the class statement does" -- More appropriate I would say:
The metaclass is the type's type. So in the code above, the type of MyModel is ChainedMeta (try type(MyModel)) or in other words, MyModel is an instancee of ChainedMeta.
Clearly any class, as any object, can only have one type, so can only have a metaclass.
Just for sake of clarity

Comment: terribly sorry, I downvoted by mistake (touched on a touch screen), saw my -1 cost later and realized I did this, too late to revert.  have a  on me, good answer.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know any way to "mix" metaclasses, but you can inherit and override them just like you would normal classes.

Say I've got a BaseModel:

```
class BaseModel(object):
    __metaclass__ = Blah
```

and you now you want to inherit this in a new class called MyModel, but you want to insert some additional functionality into the metaclass, but otherwise leave the original functionality intact. To do that, you'd do something like:

```
class MyModelMetaClass(BaseModel.__metaclass__):
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        do_custom_stuff()
        super(MyModelMetaClass, cls).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        do_more_custom_stuff()

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    __metaclass__ = MyModelMetaClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @jochenritzel, the following simplifies the combining step:

```
def combine_classes(*args):
    name = "".join(a.__name__ for a in args)
    return type(name, args, {})


class ABCSomething(object, metaclass=combine_classes(SomethingMeta, ABCMeta)):
    pass
```

Here, `type(name, bases, dict)` works like a dynamic `class` statement (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type)). Surprisingly, there doesn't seem to be a way to use the `dict` argument for setting the `metaclass` in the second step. Otherwise one could simplify the whole process down to a single function call.